# Polygon feature in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, mapguide

I have uploaded a feature to the PostGIS db and visualize it by mapguide. Now I would like to know how can I update (add) features from database directly. Can I add a new row from the web form directly? Can the mapguide help to generate the new feature? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add features (I'm guessing shapes) to your new table from some other table in the database:

```
INSERT INTO "NewTable"
(
"Shape"
)
SELECT  "Shape"
FROM    "OldTable"
```

To add features that you are just entering in by hand, this would be a primitive, but effective way:

```
INSERT INTO "NewTable"
(
"Shape"
)
VALUES
( ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((10 10,11 11,11 12),(12 13,13 12,15 14))', 2913))
```

'2913' here is referring to the SRID, something you will have to identify for yourself.

I'm sure your question might require a more complex answer, but in its current form these two answers should get you off to a good start.

Comment: Thanks for letting me to know the start point. I planned to create a web form, in which the textbox, map to be provided for user to input.